# Enforce typings when using bind

Tags: typescript, function-binding

I'm trying to create a bound version of a function which has its arguments pre-set however I am unable to get any sort of type checks on the `bind` method.

Here's my code:

```
interface I {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

function doSomethingWithValue(value: I) {
  // Do something
}

const ivalue: I = { a: 'a', b: 'b' };

// No error as expected.
doSomethingWithValue(ivalue);

//"Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'I'" as expected.
doSomethingWithValue('a');

// No error. Not what I expected
const bound = doSomethingWithValue.bind(null, 'a');

// Will fail
bound();
```

It seems that currently the TypeScript signature of `bind` is

```
bind(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;
```

Is there any way I could get types checks to work correctly with `bind`?

I've tried creating an `index.d.ts` but I am stuck on how to declare function parameters as a generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is compiler option in `3.2` and newer, called `strictBindCallApply` documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028). You can also just enable `strict` which also enables `strictBindCallApply`

With this option active you will get an error on this line:

```
const bound = doSomethingWithValue.bind(null, 'a');
```

Answer (score -2):

You may look at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212

Seems that even MS doesn't know how to make bind, call and apply strongly typed

Comment: The issue is marked as fixed and references the PR I reference in my answer. It is now possible since 3.2 (Please delete the answer as is factually incorrect)